# ¿Cómo borrar las vocales dentro de un String en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un `arrayList` con diversas cadenas y quiero que dentro de cada elemento borre solo las vocales y no se si eso es posible.
Mi código de ejemplo es este.

```
    ArrayList < String > al = new ArrayList <  >();
    al.add("abc")
    al.remove(1, "[a,A,e,E,i,I,o,O,u,U]")
    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {   
       System.out.print(al.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`, de la siguiente forma:

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add("El oceano es azul");
lista.add("El ñandú se PERDIÓ");

for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); ++i) {
    lista.set(i, lista.get(i).replaceAll("(?iu)[aeiouáéíóúü]", ""));
}

for(String s : lista) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Nota: como sugirió @Mariano utilizando el flag `(?i)` se evita repetir los caracteres para las mayúsculas, y con `u` para que también funcione con mayúsculas de acuerdo a equivalencias Unicode.

Comment: con `(?i)[aeiou]` podés evitarte algunos caracteres.

Comment: no tenia idea que existian esos flags en java :)

Comment: Los `(?modificadores)` embebidos existen en todos los dialectos de regex *compatibles con Perl*, especialmente útil para `String#replaceAll()`, que no acepta un parámetro con modificadores. Y es una lástima que no haya una versión embebida para [`CANON_EQ`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CANON_EQ) que permita coincidir con [NFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms)s.

Comment: Ciertamente el pingüino también merece muestra atención

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar las vocales de un `String` es de la siguiente forma:

```
String sms = "murcielago";
String e = sms.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
System.out.println(e);
```

esto retorna `mrclg`. Ahora, para modificar el `ArrayList` y aplicarle esto, es de la siguiente forma:

```
// se crea el ArrayList y se llena
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>() {
    {
        add("Hola");
        add("Mundo");
        add("murcielago");
    }
};

// se itera el ArrayList y se remueve las vocales
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    String e = al.get(i).replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
    // se modifica la variable en el ArrayList
    al.set(i, e);
}
// se imprime el ArrayList (esto es de las nuevas funcionalidades de Java 8)
al.forEach(System.out::println);
```

al método `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` se le pasa dos `String`, el primero es una [expresión regular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) y el segundo parámetro es por cual lo vas a reemplazar. Saludos